# Dsitribution of $\bar{X}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}{n}$

Tags: probability

$X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are i.i.d. we define $\bar{X}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}{n}$ what is the probability distribution of $\bar{X}$ if $X_i$ has a distribution $N\left(\mu, \sigma^{2}\right)$?
And what probability distribution has $\bar{X}$ when $X_i$ has a $Poisson(\lambda)$ distribution?

Find PDF

I think by Central limit theorem when $X_i$ has distribution $N\left(\mu, \sigma^{2}\right)$
by the Central limit theorem $\bar{X}$ has a normal distribution

Also when $X_i$ has a $Poisson(\lambda)$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$ we can aproximate to a Normal distribution and then $\bar{X}$ will have a normal distribution

Answer (score 2):

1. $X\sim N(\mu;\sigma^2)$

In this case, using properties of gaussian, the sample mean is still gaussian

$$\overline{X}_n\sim N\left(\mu;\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$$

2. $X\sim Po(\lambda)$

$$\mathbb{P}\left[\overline{X}_n=\frac{k}{n}\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=k\right]=\frac{e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^k}{k!}$$

$k=0,1,2,\dots$

this is the exact distribution of the sample mean from a Poisson $Po(\lambda)$